# UITableView content size incorrect

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

having some issues with my table view. If the content height is greater than the frame for some reason it uses the frame height as the content size. I can't properly scroll the table.

There is a method in my code that updates the data source. I then call:

```
tableView.reloadData()
```

The content size is incorrect. I have tried calling `tableView.layoutIfNeeded()` and `tableView.setNeedsDisplay()` after the reload. Nothing changes though. I have even tried manually setting the contentSize height to a very large number after the reload just to see if I can scroll, this also doesn't work. Any ideas what I might be doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you show more code in your viewController class?

Comment: are you used auto layot or auto resizing